# Dependent objects not destroyed when parent object is destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models, Story and User. Each Story belongs_to to a certain user. However, calling a User's .destroy method does *not* destroy the Stories it owns (and, of course, this then raises an SQL error because of the foreign key constraint). Here is the relevant code from the models (with irrelevant stuff omitted, obviously):

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'author', primary_key: 'name'
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :name
  has_many :stories, foreign_key: 'author', primary_key: 'name'
end
```

And here are the table definitions from schema.rb (again, with irrelevant columns omitted):

```
create_table "stories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "author", null: false
  t.index["author"], name: "index_stories_on_author", using: :btree
end
create_table "users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name", null: false
  t.index ["name"], name: "index_users_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree
end
add_foreign_key "stories", "users", column: "author", primary_key: "name"
```

Things I have tried that do *not* work:

- Removing the foreign key constraint. (This prevents the SQL error, but does not remove the story from the database.)
- Adding "dependent: :destroy" to the belongs_to statement.

Random facts that may be relevant but probably aren't: Story also owns some chapter objects. I am using PostgreSQL. I have the composite_primary_keys gem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have it a bit backwards. `Story` depends on `User`, so the `dependent: :destroy` directive belongs in `User` something like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :name
  has_many :stories, foreign_key: 'author', primary_key: 'name', dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! (This still causes the SQL error, but I can handle that by either removing the foreign key constraint or using :delete_all instead of :destroy)

Comment: Update: I figured out I can prevent the SQL error by using on_delete: :cascade